# Deploying Node/Mongo to Openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

Hello I'm trying to get Node/Mongo service going on Openshift, here's what it looks like:

```
 var db = new mongodb.Db('myServiceName',
   new mongodb.Server('mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST','$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT', {}));
 db.open(function (err, db_p) {
   if (err) { throw err; }
   db.authenticate('$USER', '$PASS', function (err, replies) {
     if (err) { throw err; }
     // should be connected and authenticated.
     // ...
```

The app was created using rhc:

```
$ rhc create-app myServiceName nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2.4
```

The console shows the app was started and is running, and on cURL the response is `503`

My logs don't show an error, however, the dB is obviously not live. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mongodb driver supports connection with username/password, then use OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL instead of OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST

OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL gives you this format:

mongodb://admin:password@127.4.99.1:27017/

and OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST gives you this format:

ip addres, ex: 127.4.99.1

So you can just use OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL to connect and authenticate at the same time

with mongoskin, you can just do this:

```
var db = require('mongoskin').db(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + 'dbname'+ '?auto_reconnect=true',
    {safe: true, strict: false}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are attempting to connect to a server named "`$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST`",   (not a valid URL).

Instead, you'll probably want to read the value of the `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST` environment variable to find your connection information:

```
process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST
```

I have some additional notes up here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-mongodb-on-nodejs-on-openshift

Comment: additional note link is very very helpful.  Many thanks.